# Array List without knowing the type until run time

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-3.5, arraylist

I have the following Scenario:

I have an Array List that could contain one of three possible object types that I only have access to at run time.

Fort this example lets call them:

```
ObjType1
ObjType2
ObjType3
```

I need to then loop through the array list and access several properties from each object (All three objects types contain the same two property names) and then set these values to properties on one of three other object types. Finally the new objects then need to be added to an array List.

```
ObjType4
ObjType5
ObjType6
```

As I don't know what object type the array list contains in advance I am guessing that I need to use reflection to get the objects properties. Once I have the properties I could add them to a generic class that contains the same two properties as ObjType 4,5 and 6 and then cast the generic class object to the desired object type passed in to the sub procedure/function and then add it to the array list.

what would be the best way to achieve this in your opinion?

Thanks for everyones Time

Edit - I should have mentioned before that I do not have access to change the three classes.

Comment: This is 100% the reason that interfaces exist, is that an option at all?

Comment: .net BCL already have solution..use generic List

Comment: unfortunately I don't have access to change the three classes

Answer (score 4):

You should make all three types implement an interface with those properties.
You can then use a `List<YourInterface>`.

Comment: I should have mentioned before that I don't have access to the three class types

Answer (score 1):

Use an interface, put the two properties into it and apply it to each of your three classes.  That's what they're there for.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you can't change the classes you can check the type of each item while looping:

```
string prop1 = "";
string prop2 = "";
foreach (object item in myArray)
{
   if (item is ObjType1)
   {
      prop1 = (item as ObjType1).FirstProp;
      prop2 = (item as ObjType1).SecondProp;
   }
   else if (item is ObjType2)
   {
      prop1 = (item as ObjType2).FirstProp;
      prop2 = (item as ObjType2).SecondProp;
   }
   else if (item is ObjType3)
   {
      (item as ObjType3).FirstProp = prop1;
      (item as ObjType3).SecondProp = prop2;
   }
}
```